# Calculate Hopkins Statistics (coefficient) between two groups with value whose have different ID in Rs

Tags: r, loops, cluster-computing

I have dataset “data_file” which contains five columns & 1 million rows:

- X1 "ID_Number" (numeric),
- X2 “Sample_Type”,
- X3 “Signal_X” (numeric),
- X4 “Signal_Y” (numeric),
- X5 “Signal_Z” (numeric).

Each value of the ID corresponds to a set of values “Signal_X”, “Signal_Y” and  “Signal_Z”.

```
ID_Number :: Sample_Type :: Signal_X :: Signal_Y :: Signal_Z
2             Sample         337         1538      0.6314152
2             Sample         106         1840      0.9923422
…
2             Sample          94         1445      0.9967044
10            Sample         164         1777      0.9950826
10            Sample         183         1933      0.9931457
10            Sample         176         1590      0.9690951
…
10            Sample         139         1339      0.9820210
12            Sample         154         1397      0.9700886
12            Sample         144         1206      0.9457763
… etc
```

> By scanning the ID I found the correlation coefficient b/w “Signal_X”
>   and “Signal_Y” using the following code:

```
library(plyr)
dataAE<- ddply(data_file, " ID_Number ", summarise, CorrelationCoefficient=cor(SignalX, SignalY))
View(dataAE)
```

The output should look like this.

```
    datasetID    Correlation Coefficient

1   2           0.48083503
2   3          -0.81036062
3   10         -0.32098672
4   12         -0.20251427
5   24         -0.18004939
6   51         -0.45803370
7   54         -0.59001642
8   63         -0.53976850
etc …
```

> By analogy, I'm trying to find – to Compute Hopkins statistic & find optimal number of clusters for my
>   dataset.

```
library(clustertend)
set.seed(123)
hopkins(data_file, n = nrow(data_file)-1)
```

I tried to replace CorrelationCoefficient=**cor**(SignalX, SignalY) at

```
HopkinsStatistics=hopkins(SignalX, SignalY)
```

… And without results.
Manually & without problem for each ID set I used the following code

```
library(clustertend)
# Compute Hopkins statistic for dataset
set.seed(123)
subset$sampletype<- NULL
df<-scale(subset)
res <- get_clust_tendency(df, 40, graph = FALSE)
# Hopskin statistic
res$hopkins_stat
res
```

The problem is how to automate the calculations & Using loops.
 Please help me. Thanks in advance.